# ImportError: cannot import name 'Sonnet' from 'graphs'

Tags: python, graph, pip, graph-neural-network, sonnet

The code I am trying to run is

```
import graph_nets as gn
```

and the compiler returns

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sonnet' from 'graphs'
```

which traces back to a line in the sonnet package that says `from graphs import Sonnet, D3Graph, MatplotGraph`

(I have seen many similar errors on forums and the common solution is

```
pip uninstall sonnet
pip install dm-sonnet
```

but this doesn't work for me as `pip install dm-sonnet` is responded with `requirement already satisfied` and uninstalling sonnet makes the compiler return

```
module 'sonnet' has no attribute '__version__'
```

for the same line of code I am trying to run)
The there other possible solutions?

Comment: Also, the same error occurs for ```import sonnet```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIU the correct package you need is `dm-sonnet`. But you have already installed `sonnet`. Now you need to reinstall `dm-sonnet` to remove remnants of `sonnet` and install `dm-sonnet` afresh.

```bash
pip uninstall -y dm-sonnet
pip install dm-sonnet
```

Or simply

```bash
pip install --ignore-installed dm-sonnet
```

To use `dm-sonnet` you need `tensorflow`. `dm-sonnet` doesn't automatically install `tensorflow` as a dependency so you need to install it yourself:

```bash
pip install tensorflow
```